# Android - ActionBar SearchView NullPointerException on Expand

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, searchview, drawerlayout

I have been trying to implement a SearchView in multiple Activities which will eventually filter the ListView adapter based on the input. The icon appears and is clickable, however when it expands it crashes the application with the following exception:

```
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1342)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1645)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2447)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:714)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2258)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2005)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1247)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6355)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-20 15:34:52.225: E/AndroidRuntime(24027):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried:

- Switching the actionViewClass between the support and android SearchView
- Switching the DrawerLayout to a LinearLayout
- Defaulting the view to open - Error occurs when you click on the expanded view.

I'm ready to try switching to a custom layout with an edit text for the input instead of using the actionViewClass attribute.

Any insights are appreciated.